# TLS 1.2 implement in java code of 1.7 version

Tags: java, web-services

I have a java code developed in jdk 1.7version which supports TLS1.1.
Recently my company has implemented TLS1.2 in the server.
Any suggestion or inputs on how to enable/implement TLS1.2 in my existing java code with out re-writing every thing from scratch in jdk1.8.

Here are the few things i tried to implement inside the java code but didn't work out.

```
    String check="TLSv1.2";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("https.protocols", check);
```

I have deployed the java code in jboss server and jboss version is jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Any inputs/suggestion would really helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Sameet.

Comment: Upgrade to Java 1.8.  You do not need to rewrite everything from scratch.  In fact you probably don't need to rewrite **anything**.   And note that by putting upgrades off, you are only making things more difficult (and maybe more expensive) for yourself in the long run.

Comment: my concern is jboss is in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final and if we upgrade to jdk 1.8, then the code will not work in the existing jboss version.